# How to link input in html form to its form actions in django?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

Is it possible to get value from HTML form input and use it in form action?

```
<form action="/wiki/ /" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
      <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

Here,I want the form action to be "/wiki/input_in_q/".How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

#templates

```
<form action="/wiki/input_in_q/ " method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}
      <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

Action will send you to that url: /wiki/input_in_q/. You need a view for that url I think.

## Views.py

```
from .forms import YourForm

def yourview(request):
   form = YourForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        value = form.save()
        print(value.(YourFormfeature))
    
    return render(request, 'first.html',context)
```